# AJAX Post Fatal Error Column Cannot Be Null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

I'm getting a fatal error, "Column cannot be null."

## index.php

```
<head>
  <script>
    let xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest
      ? new XMLHttpRequest()
      : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
    xhr.open('POST', 'ajax.php', true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'applications/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    xhr.send('sld=testing&tld=com&registrar=namecheap')
  </script>
</head>
```

## ajax.php

```
var_dump($_POST);    // without these var_dumps
var_dump($_REQUEST); // i receive a 500 error (internal server error)

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
  include "includes/connect_to_database.php";
  $pdo = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO domains (sld, tld, registrar) VALUES (:sld, :tld, :registrar)");
  $pdo->execute(array(
    ":sld" => $_REQUEST["sld"],
    ":tld" => $_REQUEST["tld"],
    ":registrar" => $_REQUEST["registrar"]
  ));
  $connection = null;
}
```

## fwiw: connect_to_database.php

```
try {
  $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname; charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully!";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . ".";
}
```

## MySQL Table Schema

[image]

- It says the culprit column is `sld`, so it's as if none of the data is being passed forward.
- The `responseText` is also blank.
- I get the exact same error using `$_POST` too.
- Both `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and `var_dump($_POST)` return empty arrays in the response.
- I've tried using `encodeURIComponent` on the post string, and that didn't work.
- Notably, I receive a 500 error (internal server error) if I remove the `var_dump` statements.

**Could it be that I'm not sending all of the necessary headers?**

**What exactly am I doing wrong for the data not to be passed forward?**

Comment: Should you not be using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: @Jaquarh ive tried `$_POST`, exact same error. i actually just finished updating my question

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you? Can you not use JQuery either? `$.post()`

Comment: @Jaquarh i cant really use `var_dump` because its passing the data to a different page, which obviously never opens in the browser. i really dont wanna include jquery just for this one thing

Comment: @Jaquarh `responseText` is also blank which isnt surprising since no data seems to be passed forward

Comment: In the AJAX page do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: You can use `var_dump()` because it'll be shown in your response. If it gives you nothing then your HTTP request is failing or your server-side code has errors that you have disabled.

Comment: @Jaquarh ok guys ill try `var_dump` and checking the response right now

Comment: @Jaquarh `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)` both return empty arrays in the response

Comment: @MoisheSchwartz `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)` both return empty arrays in the response

Comment: Also, why do you need `encodeURIComponent()`?  `xhr.send('params')` will do fine.

Comment: @BugWhisperer So the problem is in you JS not PHP

Comment: @Jaquarh its funny because i was getting a 500 "internal server error", but then when i added both of the `var_dumps` to the `ajax.php`, no error anymore, but empty arrays. i deleted `encodeURIComponent`. that was just something else i tried before which i hadnt removed

Comment: @MoisheSchwartz do u see anything wrong with my JS? honestly ive searched the internet high and low for AJAX Posts with Vanilla JS tutorials and theres literally nothing anywhere online. its all jQuery

Comment: could it be missing headers thats the problem or?!

Comment: "i receive a 500 error (internal server error)" - turn on error reporting, its a server-side issues and we can't see your connection file

Comment: @Jaquarh its been a while since ive used PHP. ive got this `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in my `connect_to_database.php`. what other error reporting can i enable?

Comment: upvoted to get this seen, cos I got no clue why these requests are failing to pass through the data

Comment: @Jaquarh me neither. ive reached out to a friend on here whos a far better programmer than i am, so maybe hell be able to spot the issue

Comment: can you post the table schema of your database?

Comment: @Jaquarh its solved. check the answer. ur going to want to bang ur head against a wall lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong request header.
Change it to

`xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')`

instead of

`applications/x-www-form-urlencoded`
notice one 's' here.

I think you may not require 
`$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` same time. So you may remove one of them.

Comment: ty soooo much dude. ive been at this for a couple hours now lol

Comment: Enjoy the day :)